# Automatically pull Google Doc into Pages to create PDF

Tags: pdf, pages, google-docs

Google Docs is handy for collaborative editing & referencing. But Pages makes the prettiest PDFs.

So my current process is:

- from google docs, export as word doc
- open in Pages
- export to PDF

Is there a way to automate this process?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if there is an easy way to do all of this. However, if this is something you definitely need, perhaps you can start with these two sources: "[Automate tasks in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7665004)" and "[iWork Automation: Pages AppleScript Support](https://iworkautomation.com/pages/)". You would probably also need to use the Automator app that comes with macOS along with some AppleScript code for which this, I think, is a nice brief intro: "[Using AppleScript To Automate In Numbers](https://macmost.com/using-applescript-to-automate-in-numbers.html)"

Comment: Does Pages really make 'prettier' PDFs of an imported Word document than Word or Office-compatible, without any manual intervention?

Comment: @benwiggy - yes - better typography/kerning/etc